# Where can I download Facelets tag documentation as an archive

Tags: jsf-2, tags, documentation, facelets

I am trying to download tag library documentation for JSF which includes HTML (`h`), core (`f`), Facelets(`ui`), and JSTL core (`c`). I found this documentation online at several places:

- [javaserverfaces.java.net_docs_2.1](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/)
- [javaserverfaces.java.net_nonav_2.1_facelets](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/vdldocs/facelets/)
- [docs.oracle.com_2.1_docs_facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/)

However, I did not find any downloadable JAR/archive file.

Is there any way to download this documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's included in the "binary bundle" downloads at [Mojarra download page](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html) (note: **not** just "binary").

Here's a direct link: [Mojarra 2.1.0 binary bundle](http://java.net/projects/javaserverfaces/downloads/download/release%252Fmojarra-2.1.0-FCS-binary.zip). This contains JSF 2.1 documentation. When you extract this specific file, you can find the documentation in the `/docs` folder as another zip file `mojarra-2.1.0-FCS-documentation.zip`. This zip file in turn contains several documentation folders and the particular Facelets tag documentation you're looking for is in the `/vdldocs` folder.